# Python regex ignore order of words in string

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I want to search a substring from a log, the log looks like

```
log = "blablabla targets:['123-321', '123-456'] blablabla"
```

And here's my code snippet

```
node_ids = ['123-456', '123-321']
node_ids = re.escape(str(node_ids))
expected_result = f"targets:{node_ids}"

print(re.findall(expected_result, log))
```

Output

```
[]
```

Although I have all the ID in `node_ids` but the code return nothing due to the order of ID doesn't match with log. Anyway I could make regex `findall` ignore the order of IDs?

**EDIT**
Match condition: all ID in `node_ids` are observed in `log` following the format of `expected_result`

When `node_ids = ['123-321', '123-456']`
I'm able to get the output

```
["targets:['123-321', '123-456']"]
```

Comment: Do you want to search for the brackets as well ?

Comment: What are the conditions for a match? Should a match have both node ids in either order or can a match have either node id?

Comment: I didn't make my question clear enough, added the matching criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use or operator `|`.

```python
log = "blablabla targets:['123-321', '123-456'] blablabla"
node_ids = ['123-456', '123-321']
pattern=fr"(targets:\[(?:\s*'(?:{'|'.join(node_ids)})',?\s*){'{'+str(len(node_ids))+',}'}\])"
result=re.findall(pattern, log)
```

pattern:

> "(targets:\[(?:\s*'(?:123-456|123-321)',?\s*){2,}\])"

result:

> ["targets:['123-321', '123-456']"]

To ensure that all ID in `node_ids` are observed, the pattern count number of ID matches to be equal to or greater than length of the list. So we assume that node ids could not be repeated, otherwise the input `targets:['123-321','123-321']` would be matched falsely.

Answer (score 0):

If the order does not matter then can use a set for the node_ids and compare the set of node id matches against the original set.

```python
import re

log = "blablabla targets:['123-321', '123-456'] blablabla"
node_ids = {'123-456', '123-321'}
# find all node ids in the log entry
ids = re.findall(r'\b\d{3}-\d{3}\b', log)
if node_ids == set(ids):
      print("found match:", ids)
```

**Output:**

```
found match ['123-321', '123-456']
```